# Rename branch in Gitkraken?

Tags: git, branch, rename, gitkraken

How do you rename a branch in Gitkraken?

I know how to do it from the CLI, can you do it from the GUI (or terminal - if there is some - in Gitkraken?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can't be done currently. Though you can always start a new branch from your current one in GitKraken.

Answer (score 14):

In current version 3.3.2 you can just **right-click on the branch NAME** and then select *rename* NAME.

[image]

Comment: this should be the best answer as there have been updates to GitKraken

Comment: Note: This only renames the local branch. You can push to a new remote (Set Upstream), which you can give the same (new) name. 
Afaik, there is no method for renaming remote branches directly from within GitKraken.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new branch in GitKraken, then immediately remove the wrong-named-branch. Else you will remain with many branches.

This is one of many bugs in Gitkraken.

Answer (score 1):

Delete remote branch, rename local branch and push to origin (as new one).